# Combine [l2-cache] and [l3-cache] into [cpu-cache]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[l2-cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/l2-cache): 6 questions

[l3-cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/l3-cache): 1 question

Is it really necessary to be so specific? We already have [cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cache) and [cpu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu) which together cover the CPU cache. [cpu-cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu-cache) could be created but having separate tags for each level of cache is unnecessary, in my opinion.

---

I've just done a [search](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu+cache) for [cpu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu)[cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cache). Out of those (15) questions, some were about the CPU cache in general or about all three levels and quite a few others could be given more than one of the L1, L2 and L3 cache tags.

Thoughts?

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with making those synonyms of `cpu-cache`.

Comment: I'd imagine the distinction would only (and even then very rarely) be useful on SO, but certainly not here on SU.

Comment: Tag creation has a minimum rep requirement, and l3-cache was just creates yesterday. There might be quite a few other fuitable questions whose askers didn't have the rep. I wouldn't hold the question count against those tags.

Comment: @DanielBeck Even then `cpu-cache` would be better; otherwise the tags are just being too specific. Are you saying we should make a `l1-cache`? How about a `l4-cache` for a question asking why they aren't used? The level of cache the question is about, if necessary, can be in the question itself.

Comment: You're responding to what I didn't write. I just wrote that question count shouldn't (yet) be held against these tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create [cpu-cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu-cache) and make both [l2-cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/l2-cache) and [l3-cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/l3-cache) synonyms of it.

Comment: this is done. you'll have to search for [tag:cpu]+[tag:cache] & update them to [tag:cpu-cache] manually though.

Answer (score 0):

Put both [cpu](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cpu) and [cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/cache) on those questions and just remove [l2-cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/l2-cache) and [l3-cache](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/l3-cache).

Comment: you are answering your own question with two differ answers?

Comment: @avirk present 2 different answers is not rare & for meta discussions, it's good to see all POV